como agregar archivo animate hacia HTML para que se cree un slider ya sea con botones o automáticamente
intento agregar archivos animate hacia html pero no me sale lo que que quiero hacer es hacer un slider de animate luego pasarlo a html y asi crear una pagina web con un slider incluido

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

esta es una manera de hacerlo automatico con CSS y HTML
index.html

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider" id="slider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide" id="slide1">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="caption">Texto llamativo</p>
            <img src="img1.png" alt="photo 1">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide2">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="caption">Texto llamativo</p>
            <img src="img2.png" alt="photo 2">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide3">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="caption">Texto llamativo</p>
            <img src="img3.png" alt="photo 3">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide4">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="caption">Texto llamativo</p>
            <img src="img4.png" alt="photo 4">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide5">
          <a href="#">
             <p class="caption">Texto llamativo</p>
             <img src="img2.png" alt="photo 5">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <p class="caption">Texto llamativo</p>
            <img src="img1.png" alt="photo 1">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="slider-controler">
        <li><a href="#slide1">&bullet;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide2">&bullet;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide3">&bullet;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide4">&bullet;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide5">&bullet;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>`

estilos.css
@keyframes slide {
0% { transform: translateX(0); }
10% { transform: translateX(0); }

15% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
30% { transform: translateX(-100%); }

35% { transform: translateX(-200%); }
50% { transform: translateX(-200%); }

55% { transform: translateX(-300%); }
70% { transform: translateX(-300%); }

75% { transform: translateX(-400%); }
90% { transform: translateX(-400%); }

95% { transform: translateX(-500%); }
100% { transform: translateX(-500%); }
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }

body {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
position: relative;
}

.slides {
position: relative;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
width: 100vw;
flex-shrink: 0;
animation-name: slide;
animation-duration: 20s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.slides:hover .slide {
animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slide img {
width: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
}

.slide a {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.caption {
color: white;
text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
font-size: 8vw;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8vw;
right: 4vw;
}

.slide:target {
animation-name: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 50;
}

.slider-controler {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 100;
}

.slider-controler li {
margin: 0 0.5rem;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

.slider-controler a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.slide {
    width: 1200px;
}

.caption {
    font-size: 96px;
    bottom: 96px;
    right: 50px;
}
}`


https://www.espai.es/blog/2020/11/como-hacer-un-slider-solo-con-html-y-css/
